# PerformanceAnalytics + data.frame: Formatting issue when using package functions

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I'm trying to pass a data.frame with dates in the rownames into a `PerformanceAnalytics` (package) function.

My data is below, I get the following error message when trying to run the code

```
> charts.PerformanceSummary(x$Return)
Error in checkData(R) : 
  The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'.
```

How can this be solved? I thought that PerformanceAnalytics would recognize my rows as dates automatically.

My data

```
> str(x)
'data.frame':   201 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Open     : num  69 67.8 64 67.2 68 ...
 $ High     : num  70 69 67.8 68.8 70.8 ...
 $ Low      : num  67 66 63.2 64.5 67.5 ...
 $ Close    : num  68.5 66 67.2 68 68.5 ...
 $ Volume   : num  2163200 2456100 2783000 2200300 2418000 ...
 $ Adj.Close: num  55 53 54 54.6 55 ...
 $ Return   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

> x
             Open   High    Low  Close   Volume Adj.Close       Return
2008-11-28  69.00  70.00  67.00  68.50  2163200   54.9989  0.000000000
2008-12-01  67.75  69.00  66.00  66.00  2456100   52.9916  0.000000000
2008-12-02  64.00  67.75  63.25  67.25  2783000   53.9953  0.000000000
2008-12-03  67.25  68.75  64.50  68.00  2200300   54.5974  0.000000000
2008-12-04  68.00  70.75  67.50  68.50  2418000   54.9989  0.000000000
2008-12-05  68.00  68.75  63.50  64.50  2162200   51.7873  0.000000000
2008-12-08  67.25  73.50  67.25  72.00  4363100   57.8090  0.000000000
2008-12-09  71.25  76.25  70.00  74.50  4266500   59.8163  0.000000000
2008-12-10  73.75  78.00  73.00  77.50  3395900   62.2250  0.000000000
2008-12-11  76.75  76.75  74.25  76.00  2474600   61.0207  0.000000000
2008-12-12  74.00  74.75  72.25  74.50  3141800   59.8163  0.000000000
2008-12-15  70.00  74.50  67.25  67.25  7125600   53.9953  0.000000000
2008-12-16  66.25  69.50  66.00  69.50  3063200   55.8018  0.000000000
2008-12-17  69.25  70.00  67.00  70.00  2543400   56.2032  0.000000000
2008-12-18  69.50  73.50  69.25  72.25  4366000   58.0098  0.000000000
2008-12-19  70.50  72.00  69.75  71.75  2346600   57.6083  0.000000000
2008-12-22  70.50  71.00  68.25  69.75  3057600   56.0025  0.000000000
2008-12-23  68.75  69.50  67.50  69.25  2327700   55.6011  0.000000000
2008-12-24  69.25  69.25  69.25  69.25        0   55.6011  0.000000000
2008-12-25  69.25  69.25  69.25  69.25        0   55.6011  0.000000000
2008-12-26  69.25  69.25  69.25  69.25        0   55.6011  0.000000000
2008-12-29  69.00  69.75  67.50  68.00  1187600   54.5974  0.000000000
2008-12-30  67.75  68.50  66.50  66.75  1888700   53.5938  0.000000000
2008-12-31  66.75  66.75  66.75  66.75        0   53.5938  0.000000000
2009-01-01  66.75  66.75  66.75  66.75        0   53.5938  0.000000000
2009-01-02  67.75  72.75  67.00  72.25  1887500   58.0098  0.000000000
2009-01-05  73.75  75.50  73.00  74.25  2020400   59.6156  0.000000000
2009-01-06  74.25  74.25  74.25  74.25        0   59.6156  0.000000000
2009-01-07  73.75  75.00  73.50  74.50  2962600   59.8163  0.000000000
2009-01-08  73.00  74.25  71.00  72.25  2239100   58.0098  0.000000000
2009-01-09  72.00  72.25  70.25  71.25  1983600   57.2069  0.000000000
2009-01-12  69.50  71.00  69.00  69.75  1487000   56.0025  0.000000000
2009-01-13  68.75  69.75  67.75  68.75  2859100   55.1996  0.000000000
2009-01-14  69.75  69.75  63.25  64.25  2586900   51.5865  0.000000000
2009-01-15  64.00  66.50  60.75  63.00  4090800   50.5829  0.000000000
2009-01-16  65.00  66.00  64.00  64.75  2455600   51.9880  0.000000000
2009-01-19  66.00  66.00  64.75  65.50  2839200   52.5902  0.000000000
2009-01-20  66.00  66.75  62.25  62.75  2787600   50.3822  0.000000000
2009-01-21  62.00  67.50  61.75  65.25  5090700   52.3894  0.000000000
2009-01-22  67.00  69.00  65.50  65.75  2994600   52.7909  0.000000000
2009-01-23  64.75  66.00  61.25  62.00  4463400   49.7800  0.000000000
2009-01-26  62.00  65.75  61.50  65.75  3698700   52.7909  0.000000000
2009-01-27  66.00  67.25  64.75  65.75  3445900   52.7909  0.000000000
2009-01-28  66.25  69.00  66.00  67.00  2766400   53.7945  0.000000000
2009-01-29  67.00  67.25  62.25  62.75  2090700   50.3822  0.000000000
2009-01-30  63.00  63.75  59.00  60.50  6437600   48.5757  0.000000000
2009-02-02  60.25  62.00  58.75  60.25  3267600   48.3749  0.000000000
2009-02-03  60.75  62.50  59.25  62.50  3148000   50.1815  0.000000000
2009-02-04  62.75  69.50  61.75  68.25  6579500   54.7982  0.000000000
2009-02-05  66.00  69.50  66.00  69.00  6733600   55.4003  0.000000000
2009-02-06  69.00  71.00  68.25  70.00  5031600   56.2032  0.000000000
2009-02-09  69.50  72.00  68.75  71.75  3794200   57.6083  0.000000000
2009-02-10  70.25  72.00  69.75  70.75  2991500   56.8054  0.000000000
2009-02-11  68.75  70.75  68.25  68.50  2566400   54.9989  0.000000000
2009-02-12  67.75  70.25  66.75  70.00  3083800   56.2032  0.000000000
2009-02-13  70.25  71.50  68.00  69.25  2227000   55.6011  0.000000000
2009-02-16  68.50  69.25  67.25  68.75  1087100   55.1996  0.000000000
2009-02-17  67.50  67.50  65.00  65.50  1630200   52.5902  0.000000000
2009-02-18  65.00  65.50  62.50  65.00    40400   52.1887  0.000000000
2009-02-19  65.00  68.00  64.50  66.50  2701100   53.3931  0.000000000
2009-02-20  64.25  65.00  60.75  61.25  5534300   49.1778  0.000000000
2009-02-23  62.00  62.50  58.50  58.75  2524300   47.1706  0.000000000
2009-02-24  58.75  60.25  56.75  58.00  5117600   46.5684  0.000000000
2009-02-25  59.50  61.75  59.25  60.25  4418400   48.3749  0.000000000
2009-02-26  61.50  64.50  60.50  63.50  6482600   50.9844  0.000000000
2009-02-27  61.50  62.75  60.00  62.00  2834500   49.7800  0.000000000
2009-03-02  61.25  61.25  58.00  59.50  3087100   47.7727  0.000000000
2009-03-03  60.00  60.75  57.75  58.50  2606300   46.9698  0.000000000
2009-03-04  60.00  60.00  58.00  59.75  4554800   47.9735  0.000000000
2009-03-05  59.00  59.75  57.25  58.00  2777600   46.5684  0.000000000
2009-03-06  56.50  58.75  56.50  57.50  3338300   46.1669  0.000000000
2009-03-09  58.50  58.75  57.00  58.00  3708500   46.5684  0.000000000
2009-03-10  58.00  61.00  57.50  60.25  5163300   48.3749  0.000000000
2009-03-11  60.00  62.75  59.00  61.50  3668700   49.3786  0.000000000
2009-03-12  61.50  61.75  58.50  61.25  3404600   49.1778  0.000000000
2009-03-13  63.00  64.00  60.75  62.00  4048500   49.7800  0.000000000
2009-03-16  63.00  64.50  62.25  62.50  2945300   50.1815  0.000000000
2009-03-17  62.75  62.75  60.50  60.75  2369800   48.7764  0.000000000
2009-03-18  62.25  62.50  59.25  60.25  1968600   48.3749  0.000000000
2009-03-19  61.00  64.75  60.25  64.25  3730400   51.5865  0.000000000
2009-03-20  63.75  65.00  63.50  63.50  3186200   50.9844  0.000000000
2009-03-23  64.75  65.50  63.00  65.50  2738400   52.5902  0.000000000
2009-03-24  65.50  66.00  63.00  64.50  2994200   51.7873  0.000000000
2009-03-25  63.75  69.00  62.75  67.75  4342500   54.3967  0.000000000
2009-03-26  67.00  69.25  66.75  68.00     8300   54.5974  0.000000000
2009-03-27  67.75  69.50  66.75  68.50  3407200   54.9989  0.000000000
2009-03-30  66.75  67.00  63.75  64.50  3123200   51.7873  0.000000000
2009-03-31  64.00  66.25  63.00  64.50  3261600   51.7873  0.000000000
2009-04-01  64.50  64.75  60.75  64.25  6808900   51.5865  0.000000000
2009-04-02  67.00  73.25  66.75  72.75  8180500   58.4112  0.000000000
2009-04-03  72.00  76.50  71.25  75.75  5628500   60.8199  0.000000000
2009-04-06  76.00  76.75  74.25  75.00  3238900   60.2178  0.000000000
2009-04-07  75.75  76.00  72.25  73.75  3765800   59.2141  0.000000000
2009-04-08  72.00  75.75  71.50  75.50  3177100   60.6192  0.000000000
2009-04-09  75.50  76.00  74.25  76.00   887600   61.0207  0.000000000
2009-04-10  76.00  76.00  76.00  76.00        0   61.0207  0.000000000
2009-04-13  76.00  76.00  76.00  76.00        0   61.0207  0.000000000
2009-04-14  78.00  80.75  77.00  79.00  3923200   63.4294  0.000000000
2009-04-15  78.00  79.00  75.75  76.00  2425700   61.0207  0.000000000
2009-04-16  77.50  79.50  76.00  79.25  3331200   63.6301  0.000000000
2009-04-17  79.25  83.00  79.00  81.25  4058600   65.2359  0.000000000
2009-04-20  80.00  80.50  75.75  76.75  3682800   61.6228  0.000000000
2009-04-21  76.25  76.75  73.25  75.75  3293500   60.8199  0.000000000
2009-04-22  84.00  91.50  82.00  88.00 10525000   70.6555  0.000000000
2009-04-23  89.75  92.75  88.75  90.25  5664200   72.4620  0.000000000
2009-04-24  90.75  94.75  89.50  93.75  3982600   75.2722  0.000000000
2009-04-27  92.25 100.25  91.75  97.50  4702300   78.2831  0.000000000
2009-04-28  95.75  96.00  92.25  95.00  6479800   76.2758  0.000000000
2009-04-29  94.50  97.50  92.75  95.00  2565300   76.2758  0.000000000
2009-04-30  95.00  96.75  92.00  92.00  2480500   73.8671  0.000000000
2009-05-01  92.00  92.00  92.00  92.00        0   73.8671  0.000000000
2009-05-04  95.75 100.00  94.00 100.00  3653000   80.2903  0.086956169
2009-05-05 100.00 101.75  97.75  97.75     3400   78.4838 -0.022499605
2009-05-06  98.00 104.00  96.50 102.75  4010500   82.4983  0.051150683
2009-05-07 104.25 105.00  98.50  99.75  5145800   80.0896 -0.029196965
2009-05-08 101.25 103.25  99.25 100.25  2782200   80.4911  0.005013135
2009-05-11 100.25 100.75  93.50  97.25  3925100   78.0824 -0.029925048
2009-05-12  96.50  99.00  94.00  94.50  2770700   75.8744 -0.028277819
2009-05-13  94.75  95.50  88.25  89.00  4618500   71.4584 -0.058201449
2009-05-14  89.00  92.75  87.50  91.75  2712300   73.6664  0.030899097
2009-05-15  94.00  94.00  91.00  92.50  1675400   74.2686  0.008174690
2009-05-18  91.25  97.75  91.00  97.00  3331500   77.8816  0.048647746
2009-05-19  99.25 103.75  98.75  99.50  5343000   79.8889  0.025773739
2009-05-20 100.25 101.00  98.50 100.25  1169700   80.4911  0.007537968
2009-05-21 100.25 100.25 100.25 100.25        0   80.4911  0.000000000
2009-05-22  98.00  99.50  95.75  96.75  2095400   77.6809 -0.034913177
2009-05-25  96.50  97.75  95.50  96.00  1016600   77.0787 -0.007752227
2009-05-26  94.75  96.75  90.75  96.00  3642600   77.0787  0.000000000
2009-05-27  97.50  98.00  96.75  97.50  3729400   78.2831  0.015625588
2009-05-28  96.25  99.00  96.00  98.00  3575300   78.6845  0.005127543
2009-05-29  99.25 100.00  95.25  95.50  3396900   76.6773 -0.025509471
2009-06-01  97.00 100.75  97.00 100.75  1963400   80.8925  0.054973245
2009-06-02  98.00  99.25  95.75  98.00  3547300   78.6845 -0.027295485
2009-06-03  98.75  98.75  95.75  96.75  1865100   77.6809 -0.012754736
2009-06-04  97.25  98.00  96.75  98.00  2496300   78.6845  0.012919521
2009-06-05  98.75 102.25  98.50 100.25  3226800   80.4911  0.022960049
2009-06-08 100.25 101.00  97.25  99.50  2333200   79.8889 -0.007481572
2009-06-09 100.25 103.00 100.25 102.25  4285900   82.0969  0.027638383
2009-06-10 103.25 105.00 102.50 103.50  3933000   83.1005  0.012224579
2009-06-11 105.75 109.00 105.50 108.00  7400700   86.7136  0.043478679
2009-06-12 108.50 110.50 107.50 109.25  3325200   87.7172  0.011573732
2009-06-15 108.25 108.25 103.50 104.00  1848400   83.5019 -0.048055569
2009-06-16 103.75 105.00 102.75 102.75    21000   82.4983 -0.012018888
2009-06-17 101.50 102.25  97.50  99.00  4273700   79.4874 -0.036496510
2009-06-18  99.75 100.75  98.25 100.00  1910400   80.2903  0.010100972
2009-06-19 100.00 100.00 100.00 100.00        0   80.2903  0.000000000
2009-06-22  99.00  99.75  94.00  94.50  3168000   75.8744  0.000000000
2009-06-23  94.50  98.75  94.25  97.50  2356000   78.2831  0.000000000
2009-06-24  99.00 102.50  98.00 102.00  2184800   81.8961  0.046153001
2009-06-25 101.50 103.00 100.00 103.00  1950300   82.6990  0.009803886
2009-06-26 105.00 107.25 103.75 104.50  2649900   83.9034  0.014563659
2009-06-29 105.00 109.25 104.50 108.75  2420700   87.3157  0.040669389
2009-06-30 109.75 110.50 107.25 107.75  2999500   86.5128 -0.009195368
2009-07-01 108.50 111.50 108.50 111.00  2335800   89.1223  0.030163167
2009-07-02 110.50 111.00 106.75 108.00  3151600   86.7136 -0.027026906
2009-07-03 108.00 108.50 106.00 107.00   809300   85.9107 -0.009259217
2009-07-06 106.75 107.50 104.75 106.25  2030400   85.3085 -0.007009604
2009-07-07 107.00 109.50 105.75 107.50  2644100   86.3121  0.011764361
2009-07-08 107.00 108.75 106.25 106.75  3189000   85.7099 -0.006977006
2009-07-09 108.50 110.25 108.50 109.00  3032300   87.5165  0.021078078
2009-07-10 109.25 111.50 108.25 109.25  2637000   87.7172  0.002293282
2009-07-13 108.75 111.25 106.75 110.00  1901300   88.3194  0.006865244
2009-07-14 111.25 112.00 109.25 110.75  2061800   88.9215  0.006817302
2009-07-15 112.00 116.75 111.25 116.75  4185600   93.7390  0.054176999
2009-07-16 125.00 130.50 124.25 127.50  9537100  102.3702  0.092076937
2009-07-17 129.00 131.00 126.25 129.75  2709700  104.1767  0.017646737
2009-07-20 130.00 132.00 129.50 131.00  1762400  105.1803  0.009633632
2009-07-21 131.50 132.25 126.50 127.25  3644800  102.1695 -0.028625132
2009-07-22 127.50 132.25 127.50 130.75  4810100  104.9796  0.027504294
2009-07-23 131.25 131.25 126.75 130.00  3299000  104.3774 -0.005736353
2009-07-24 129.00 133.50 129.00 133.00    52200  106.7861  0.023076835
2009-07-27 134.50 134.75 130.00 132.00  2038900  105.9832 -0.007518769
2009-07-28 132.00 132.75 128.75 130.00  2058000  104.3774 -0.015151458
2009-07-29 130.00 131.50 127.00 128.25  2245700  102.9724 -0.013460768
2009-07-30 130.25 134.25 129.25 134.00  3305500  107.5890  0.044833373
2009-07-31 133.25 138.25 133.00 135.00  3155600  108.3920  0.007463588
2009-08-03 135.00 138.00 134.00 137.25  1916800  110.1985  0.016666359
2009-08-04 136.75 136.75 131.00 132.50  2139700  106.3847 -0.034608457
2009-08-05 132.00 136.00 132.00 134.50  2780800  107.9905  0.015094276
2009-08-06 135.50 139.25 135.00 136.00  2847500  109.1949  0.011152833
2009-08-07 135.25 141.00 134.50 140.00  3169600  112.4065  0.029411630
2009-08-10 139.75 139.75 137.75 139.00  1840700  111.6036 -0.007142825
2009-08-11 138.75 140.00 135.00 135.25  2143500  108.5927 -0.026978520
2009-08-12 134.75 138.50 134.50 138.50  2653600  111.2021  0.024029240
2009-08-13 139.00 149.75 138.75 143.75  8064400  115.4174  0.037906658
2009-08-14 144.25 148.50 141.50 142.75    40600  114.6145 -0.006956490
2009-08-17 141.25 142.00 137.25 137.50  2820500  110.3992 -0.036778069
2009-08-18 138.00 139.00 134.50 137.25  3389500  110.1985 -0.001817948
2009-08-19 136.00 139.75 134.25 138.50  3337300  111.2021  0.009107202
2009-08-20 141.00 148.25 141.00 147.50  5540400  118.4282  0.064981686
2009-08-21 147.50 154.00 147.25 153.50  5896100  123.2457  0.040678656
2009-08-24 155.50 157.00 150.00 154.00  3100300  123.6471  0.003256909
2009-08-25 151.00 151.00 148.75 149.75  3166000  120.2348 -0.027597089
2009-08-26 148.80 149.80 142.40 146.30  4975000  117.4648 -0.023038255
2009-08-27 144.70 146.30 142.70 145.30  2433000  116.6619 -0.006835239
2009-08-28 147.10 153.50 146.40 152.50  4590400  122.4428  0.049552596
2009-08-31 151.50 152.75 146.80 147.50  2984800  118.4282 -0.032787555
2009-09-01 148.60 148.90 145.10 145.30  3402800  116.6619 -0.014914522
2009-09-02 144.00 146.30 140.50 145.60  3403400  116.9027  0.002064084
2009-09-03 146.10 148.40 144.90 147.00  2835000  118.0268  0.009615689
2009-09-04 149.40 153.25 149.10 153.25  3937700  123.0449  0.042516615
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x$Return` is a vector, not a `data.frame` and therefore does not have `rownames`. Use `x["Return"]` or `as.xts(d)[,"Return"]` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I tried x[, 'Return'] before and it gave me also a vector, but x[, c('Return', 'Open')] gives back a data.frame, is there a particular reason for this?

Comment: @uncool you can also use `x[, 'Return', drop=FALSE]` to return a single column as a `data.frame`. See `?\`[\`` for more

Comment: @uncool: that's why I suggested `x["Return"]`, which returns a data.frame.